# Trying to get values form a list inside a JSON respons

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary, key, httpresponse

My goal is to loop over a JSON response, grab two values, and build out an API call to load information into a POST to create a policy I am building.

To start out on this, I am trying to get two values from a JSON response to assign as variables to build the POST call, which will be the second step to this. As each different "id" and "name" key is assigned, I would like to build out a JSON payload and send the POST calls one at a time. The keys "id" and "name" occurs multiple times in the response payload and I am having issues capturing the two keys.

JSON response

```
data =  {
 "data":[
 {
    "id":"02caf2be-3245-4d3d",
    "name":"ORA-FIN-ACTG",
    "description":"Oracle",
    "links":{
       "web":"https://com/",
       "api":"https://com/"
    }
 },
 {
    "id":"03af2f46-fad6-41a1",
    "name":"NBCMAINFRAME",
    "description":"Network",
    "links":{
       "web":"https://com/",
       "api":"https://com/"
    }
 },
 {
    "id":"0649628b-0e3b-48df",
    "name":"CAMS",
    "description":"Customer",
    "links":{
       "web":"https://com/",
       "api":"https://com/"
    }
 },
 {
    "id":"069d4bcf-3e50-4105",
    "name":"SHAREPOINTSITES",
    "description":"Sharepoint",
    "links":{
       "web":"https://com/",
       "api":"https://com/"
    }
 }
],
"took":0.013,
"requestId":"1f364470"
```

}

I have tried various "for loops" to grab the data. Here is one of the loops below:

```
data = json.loads(data)
data[0]['data'][0]['name']
for item in range(len(data)):
print(data[item]['data'][0]['name'])
```

I have also tried reading it as a dictionary:

```
for data_dict in data:
for key, value in data_dict.items():
    team.append(key)
    id.append(value)

    print('name = ', team)
    print('id = ', id)
```

I am also getting KeyError's and TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict'.

Any help is appreciated.

FYI, this is the payload I am wanting to populate with the "name" and "id" values:

```
data= {
    "type":"alert",
    "description":"policy",
    "enabled":"true",
    "filter":{
        "type":"match-any-condition",
        "conditions":[
            {
                "field":"extra-properties",
                "key":"alertOwner",
                "operation":"equals",
                "expectedValue":name
            }
        ]
    },
    "ignoreOriginalResponders": "true",
    "ignoreOriginalTags": "true",
    "continue": "true",
    "name": str(name) + " Policy",
    "message":"{{message}}",
    "responders":[{"type":"team","id":id}],
    "alias":"{{alias}}",
    "tags":["{{tags}}"],
    "alertDescription":"{{description}}"
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain this part of the code: 
`"{} : {}".`
Is this getting to the next level in the dictionary?

Comment: No, those are just the placeholders for pretty printing the output. ```item["id"]``` and ```item["name"]``` will get you your values. I printed it using the [inbuilt string format method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON response which you have given is already a dictionary so no need to use `json.loads` for that. The multiple item list is actually nested under the `data` key. So you could just simply iterate through the array of items like this:

```py
for item in data["data"]:
    print("{} : {}".format(item["id"],item["name"]))
```

This is the output:

```
02caf2be-3245-4d3d : ORA-FIN-ACTG
03af2f46-fad6-41a1 : NBCMAINFRAME
0649628b-0e3b-48df : CAMS
069d4bcf-3e50-4105 : SHAREPOINTSITE
```